# Is it possible to pass values from properties to CSS in SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

Is it possible to have a web part in SPFx which has (for example) a property "divWidth"
and it be a numeric value in px.
Then then a div renders with the width specified in the web part?

I know you could probably do it with inline styles but can you pass the value to an SCSS file?
Thanks P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the CSS Variables, for example based on the web part properties

```
let styleBlock = { "--tileWidth": this.props.width + "px",
 "--tileHeight": this.props.height + "px" } as React.CSSProperties;
```

render it like:

```
 <div className={`${styles.linkTiles} ${styles.tileCont}`} style={styleBlock}>
```

css will be like:

```
.linkTiles {
  &.tileCont {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: left;
  }
 
  .tile,
  .tileFlip,
  .tileFront,
  .tileFront>img,
  .tileBack {
    width: var(--tileWidth);
    height: var(--tileHeight);
  }
```

[Using CSS Variables to Morph Your SPFx Design at Run Time](https://julieturner.net/2019/06/using-css-variables-to-morph-your-spfx-design-at-run-time/)